# Question mark in script breaks html

Tags: javascript, html, joomla

I have inserted a block of javascript in then body of a Joomla 2.5 article.
What I want to achieve is to open a default client email engine in order to send some information there.
The code looks like this:

```
var sendForm = function() {
   ...
   window.open('mailto:admin@admin.com?subject=mailSubject&body=mailBody');
};
```

What happens actually, when I load the page is that whatever is after the "?" is broken and appears as plain text in the UI.

For example, I have the following stuff in the UI:

```
?subject=mailSubject&body=mailBody'); }; window.onload = getTotal();
```

What is wrong? Can you help me to spot the stuff that I am doing it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a Joomla specific problem. I managed to get over it by using the `{emailcloak=off}`syntax before the actual email address.

Therefore the code looks like this `mailto:{emailcloak=off}some@email.com?subject....`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `&#63;` instead of `?`, and `&amp;` instead of `&`. If you wish, you can refer to the HTML character numbers and names [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

It will not only solve your problem, but also pass the W3C validator.

Comment: There is nothing invalid about using a `?` character in JavaScript embedded in HTML. (Or anywhere else in HTML where you can include character data).

Comment: Hi Janos, I'm affraid your solution does not work.. :(
Either with the codes, or not, I get the exact same thing in the UI, and I have no idea why... :(